# Is the innodb_lazy_drop_table problem solved?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, percona-server, xtradb

I'm researching database configuration for MySQL/MariaDB. I've been reading the configuration chapter in "High Performance MySQL". In there, it suggests that `innodb_lazy_drop_table` can be used to avoid server stalls when dropping tables if `innodb_file_per_table` is set, to stop an immediate scan of the buffer pool to invalidate pages that refer to the dropped table.

However, I also found that `innodb_lazy_drop_table` [has now been removed](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_lazy_drop_table) from XtraDB.

Does that mean the original issue is fixed, and I no longer have to worry about performance issues when dropping InnoDB/XtraDB tables? Or perhaps the lazy invalidation of pages has been enabled by default and the configuration option is all that's been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be fixed (see [percona manual](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/innodb_lazy_drop_table.html)):

> Feature has been removed because the upstream DROP TABLE implementation has been improved.

Comment: I'll drop my answer because I was reffering to the same link. +1 !!!